# Does the glue in tyre repair kits expire?

Tags: tire, repair

I have a tyre repair kit that I bought ~4 years ago. I never used it. In fact, I never used such a kit in my life.

Does the glue expire after some time, or is it good indefinitely? The tube is still sealed, but I am worried that should I need to use it, I might find that the glue has already set.

[image]

Comment: Basically it's good for 10 years or so unopened.  Once you open it maybe 2 or 3 years.  But note that the goo on the patches also dries out, probably in 5 years or so.

Comment: " In fact, I never used such a kit in my life."
You can be quite sure that whatever deity and/or statistical property of our universe will cause you a puncture in the next 5 rides. Get ready :) !

On a  slightly more serious note, I would worry about the levers becoming brittle and breaking in your hands. I have the same levers ... well, I have one left, I think I changed 4/5 tires at maximum. I suggest replacing them with some levers from the same brand, but the wider ones (the colorful ones).

Comment: @EarlGrey I did have a few punctures (too many blackberries here), but most of the time it took until the next morning for the tire to deflate. The one time it didn't, I didn't have the repair kit :-(

Comment: I'd suggest carrying spare tube on rides, and fix the puncture in the warmth and comfort of home.  No need to carry this kit on a ride.

Comment: @Criggie and when you are without the kit, then you have a puncture in the new tube because when you quickly changed the tube you forgot about checking the tires for debris/thorns/nails ... I am a pragmatic optimist: either I bring both a spare tube and a kit, or none.

Comment: @EarlGrey this is getting away from the purpose of comments, so do feel free to ask a new question, something like "what are the pros and cons of different strategies for dealing with punctures on a ride?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not indefinitely, but it is good for many years. After you open it, there could be a tendency for drying, but even that takes a very long time. Even opened and well closed glue will survive for years.

Comment: It may depend on the brand but I have a very fast drying out of used glue tubes and when I mention it others have the same experience. Better replace the tube after using it.

Comment: @Willeke That would be too wasteful for traditional vulcanization solutions. I do not have an experience of them drying out. Check them from time to time.

Comment: The last 4 tubes I used dried out within months, possible weeks. I now save up tubes with leaks and repair them when I have a few. I hope some glue maker will start with smaller tubes, for one or two repairs.

Comment: @Willeke OK, so I went to check the glue in the cheap Decathlon set that I have at home and it was indeed dry. Then I went to the shed and checked the glue in the mountainbike set (Ferdus). It certainly have not been used in the last two years. It ran OK. Sadly I lost quite a bit of it when it started to run from the tube. I guess it also depends on the quality of the glue tube and possibly also the vulcanization fluid tself.

Comment: They sell these fluids even in MUCh bigger packaging (even 0.8 l https://www.ferdus.cz/en/1-1-631/ferdus-products/repair-fluids/vulcanizing-fluids-d/vulcanizing-fluid-d-800-ml.html). They are not meant to be single use.